# React-chartjs ignoring options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

I have got this code using react-chartjs. It displays the graph but the options get ignored everytime no matter what I put there. Is there another way you are supposed to add the options into the component?

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;

var data = {
  labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'apples',
    data: [12, 19, 3, 17, 6, 3, 7]
  }]
};

var options = {
  lineTension : 0,
  fill : false,
  showLines : false 
};

const Graph = () => (
  <span>
    <h1>Heart Graph</h1>
    <LineChart  data={data} options={options} width="600" height="250"/>
  </span>
)

export default Graph
```

Comment: According to http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-dataset-structure `fill` is an attribute on a dataset, but that didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a "dataset structure" so check out the docs on options for [Line Chart Datasets](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-dataset-structure).

They suggest you should send the "options" along with your data object - in this case to the Components `data` prop.

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            data: ['data1', 'data2'],
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            ...
```

Alternatively, you can provide a more complex option object with Axis settings to the option prop.

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom'
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is change in Chart.js version 2 to version 3
for scales namespace is options.scales

scales: {
y: {
min: 0,
max: 100,
}
},
x: {
grid: {
display: true,
}
},
we use like this